# changing an iframe with a url hashtag

Tags: html, iframe

I have an iframe that I change with buttons using

```
<a href="titanors-extended-functions.html" target="iframe">
   <p>Titanors Extended Functions</p>
</a>
```

but I also want to change the Iframe with a hashtag in the URL such as https://example-of-url.com/#titanors-extended-functions

is this possible, and if so how do I do it?

Answer (score 0):

Add a name attribute to your link:

```
<a name = "yourLinksName" href="titanors-extended-functions.html" target="iframe">
   <p>Titanors Extended Functions</p>
</a>
```

And when you're linking to it, you'll use the # in the link

```
<a href="PathGoesHereAnd#yourLinksName"></a>

or

http://www.PathGoesHereAnd#yourLinksName
```

Hope that makes sense!